# Nested loops, how many times does it run?

Tags: java, loops, nested

**How many times does this nested loop run. How do I determine it by looking at the code.**

```
int i = 5, j =0;
while (i>0)
{
 j = 1;
 while (j<i )
 {
System.out.println(“Inner loop!”);
j++;
 }
 System.out.println(“Outer loop!”);
 i
```

Comment: You process it line by line just like it would run. If it's too complicated use a table.

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since you left out the `--` from the `i--` on the last row, this will never terminate.

Comment: True, well technically, it would loop around :)

Comment: Good point. Although, it'd feel like infinity considering the inner loop would then expand rather than contract as `i` grows.

Answer (score 0):

well, first off, the code isn't complete, and depending on how it completes changes the answer completely. It should be something like:

```
int i = 5, j =0;
while (i>0)
{
    j = 1;
    while (j<i )
    {
        System.out.println(“Inner loop!”);
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(“Outer loop!”);
    i++; // OR i--;
}
```

If the case is the final part is"i++" at the end it runs for an infinite number of times, because when "While(i>0) " evaluates, "i" never becomes less then 0. And "infinite" only in logic, as numbers (integers in this case) have a definite upper bound in code/compilers.

If its "i--" then its a simple matter of counting. The larger loop, [while (i>0)] will count down from 5 to 0, and quit when i is zero, that means it will will run with i=5, i=4, i=3, i=2, and i=1. This means effectively the outer loop runs 5 times, and each time it runs a little less.

J starts at 1 and counts up to just under i [while(j [lessthen] i)], meaning it will run the first time counting 1 to 4, because J starts at one, and goes to one-less-then i (5 the first time). So 4 the first time, 3 the second time, 2 the third time, 1 the forth time, and none the fifth time, because in that last case the evaluation is 1(j)[lessthen]1(i), which is false and exits the loop.

To get your final number, you count the number of times the inner loop happens successfully, in this case 4 + 3 + 2 +1 or....10 times. Assuming its "i--"

Comment: It wouldn't be truly infinite if it was written with `i++` although it would take a very long time to finish.   An `int` has an upper bound and would eventually overflow to negative and stop.

Comment: This is true, but he didn't define any sort of code system, so I sort of took a leap and assumed it was more of a logic based thing then an actual code one.

Comment: yeah its not actual code, just an example for how nested loops works, Thanks